# Deep merging hash (adding values)

Tags: crystal-lang

I need to merge several hashes. I mean having:

```
a = {:x => 72, :y => 2}
b = {:x => 34, :y => 24}
c = a.deep_merge!(b)
```

and `c` is `{:x => 106, :y => 26}`.

Is there a feature in Crystal like [`deep_merge`](https://github.com/danielsdeleo/deep_merge) in Ruby?

EDIT : The real `hash` is **more** complex

```
{"request" => {"duration" => 15100012.0, "total" => 252562.0, "per_second" => 16725.0, "bytes" => 43440664.0}, "error" => {"socket" => 0.0, "read" => 25.0, "write" => 0.0, "http" => 0.0, "timeout" => 0.0}, "latency" => {"minimum" => 234.0, "maximum" => 219466.0, "average" => 7640.0, "deviation" => 12940.0}, "percentile" => {"fifty" => 2732.0, "ninety" => 20335.0, "ninety_nine" => 65824.0, "ninety_nine_ninety" => 199536.0}}
```

in fact it's a `json` transformed in a `hash` with `PullParser`

my final goal is to add create a new hash composed by values (added) from this hash on a loop

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is not a deep merge (a recursive operation), but just a custom merge strategy.

It can be solved by calling [`Hash#merge`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Hash.html#merge%28other%3AHash%28L%2CW%29%2C%26block%3AK%2CV%2CW-%3EV%7CW%29forallL%2CW-instance-method) with a block:

```
a = {:x => 72, :y => 2}
b = {:x => 34, :y => 24}
c = a.merge(b) { |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
pp c # => {:x => 106, :y => 26}
```

Comment: You can also look at [`Hash#merge`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) for Ruby, since it works the same and currently has better documentation.